# DocumentDb: Querying without an index

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When excluding all paths from indexing, how come I am still able to perform a successful query on fields other than ID?

Excluding all paths:

```
collection.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath()
    {
        Path = "/*"
    });
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Key = "117dfd49-a71d-413b-a9b1-841e88db06e8"
```

Accordingly [this MSDN article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/):

> *When indexing is turned off, documents can be accessed only through their self-links or by queries using ID.*

**EDIT:**

When looking into the indexing policy I see what my paths aren't excluded:

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/\"_ts\"/?",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I am using consistent indexing, so surely this is not an issue of eventual consistency with the index propagation, if I understand it correctly?

Here is all the code:

```
var collectionSpec = new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId };
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { OfferType = "S1" };

collection = Client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(databaseLink, collectionSpec, requestOptions).Result;

collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;
collection.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath()
    {
        Path = "/*"
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any call to replace the document collection after setting up the new indexing policy.

You need to call `Client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()` to have your indexing policy changes take effect.

The method documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replacedocumentcollectionasync.aspx).

And here's [an article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-your-documentdb-indexing-policies-online/) written by the DocumentDB team about updating index policies online (which refers to the need to call `ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()`).

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change the code snippet to define the indexing policy on the collection spec *prior* to `client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync()` - so that it is included in the network request for creating a collection to DocumentDB.

**Setting a custom Indexing Policy at the time of Collection Creation**

```c#
var collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = "myCollection" };

collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(
    new IncludedPath { 
        Path = "/*", 
        Indexes = new Collection<Index> { 
            new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 }, 
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 }
        }
    });

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection);
```

**Updating Indexing Policy on an Existing Collection**

As [David mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739301/319795) - you can also update the index policy on an existing collection with `Client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()`.