# Cannot update the index policy

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I cannot seem to update the index policy from the C# SDK.

```
if (collection == null)
{
    collection = Client
        .CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
            databaseLink, 
            new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId },
            new RequestOptions { OfferType = "S1" })
        .Result;
}

collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IncludedPath
{
    Path = "/*",
    Indexes = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Index>
        {
            new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 },
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 },
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Point)
        }
});
```

No matter what, the index looks like this:

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/\"_ts\"/?",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

I assume this is the default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DocumentDb: Querying without an index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733740/documentdb-querying-without-an-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to change the code snippet to define the indexing policy on the collection spec *prior* to `client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync()` - so that it is included in the network request for creating a collection to DocumentDB.

**Setting a custom Indexing Policy at the time of Collection Creation**

```c#
var collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = "myCollection" };

collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(
    new IncludedPath { 
        Path = "/*", 
        Indexes = new Collection<Index> { 
            new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 }, 
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 }
        }
    });

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, collection);
```

**Updating Indexing Policy on an Existing Collection**

You can also update the index policy on an existing collection with `Client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()`.